# How to check existence in Oracle using a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to check if a column value exists using this query that actualy works fine

```
SELECT   COUNT(1)
FROM my_Table
WHERE mycolumn1 = 'BJS'
AND mycolumn2 = '100000'
```

The result is `0` that means `mycolumn2` ' s value does not exists , if The result is `1` that means it does exists

Now ,  i'm trying to add `mycolumn2` to be displayed using this

```
SELECT   COUNT(1) , mycolumn2  
FROM my_Table
WHERE mycolumn1 = 'BJS'
AND mycolumn2 = '100000'
group by mycolumn2
```

But , it does not work and it displays nothing

What i'm missing ?

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve in general words, provide sample data and desired output for this data (both in text format).

Comment: @astentx , the values are different because it is a primary key

Comment: It is because of the GROUP-BY statement in the second query. 

In the case that the table does not have any rows that match the WHERE condition (mycolumn1 = 'BJS' AND mycolumn2 = '100000'), there would be no groups produced by the GROUP-BY statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you generate at least one row for each group:

```sql
SELECT d.mycolumn2,
       COUNT(m.mycolumn2)
FROM   (SELECT '100000' AS mycolumn2 FROM DUAL) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table m
       ON (   m.mycolumn1 = 'BJS'
          AND m.mycolumn2 = d.mycolumn2)
GROUP BY d.mycolumn2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (mycolumn1 VARCHAR2(20), mycolumn2 VARCHAR2(20));
```

Outputs:

| MYCOLUMN2 | COUNT(M.MYCOLUMN2) |
| --- | --- |
| 100000 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K_gfq73O)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the GROUP-BY statement in the second query.

In the case that the table does not have any rows that match the WHERE condition (mycolumn1 = 'BJS' AND mycolumn2 = '100000'), there would be no groups produced by the GROUP-BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join so the existence of the row is optional, and count one of the columns from the joined table so you get an accurate count:

```
SELECT COUNT(my.mycolumn1),
       mt.mycolumn2  
FROM DUAL
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_Table mt
  ON mt.mycolumn1 = 'BJS' AND
     mt.mycolumn2 = '100000'
group by mt.mycolumn2
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GnnqAd6S)